# how to fix Expected response to contain an array but got an object ANgular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new one so difficult to getting this error using resource module after calling service.
can any one modify my mistake in code where i am getting wrong or just modified that pieace of which needs to rectify thanx must be appreciated.

**Format Of data Coming:-**

```
[
    brands: Array[1]
    0: Object
    __v: 0
    _id: "5251a4a34f232fc3902"
    account_id: "525072320e32971b"
    name: "Fruits"
    __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    length: 2

    categories: Array[1]
        0: Object
        __v: 0
        _id: "5251a4a34f2323fc3902"
        account_id: "5250723230e32971b"
        name: "Fruits"
        __proto__: Object
        1: Object
        length: 2
]
```

**Error:-**

[$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object

**itmsFormView.html**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="item.brand_id" id="itemBrand" >
    <option value="">Select Brand</option>
    <option ng-repeat="brand in brands" value="{{brand.brand_id}}">{{brand.name}}  </option>
</select>



 <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.category_id" id="itemCategory">           

<option value="">Select Category</option>
       <option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category.brand_id}}">{{category.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

**ItemsService.js**

```
app.factory('itemService', function ($resource) {
    return {
        getCategoryAndBrand   :  $resource("/user/categories_brands" ,{},{ TypeGetCategoryAndBrand:{method: 'get', isArray:true}})
    };
});
```

**ItemsController.js**

```
app.controller('itemsFormController', function ($rootScope, $scope, itemService, $location, $cookies, $routeParams) {
        itemService.getCategoryAndBrand.TypeGetCategoryAndBrand({}, function(response){
                console.log(response);

            },function(errorResponse){
                console.log(errorResponse);
            }
        );  
});
```

Comment: I could be wrong about this, I have to double check the documentation, but based on your error, could it be that the resource function returns an object and an array is expected?  The same way that you pass dependencies to a module as an array and not an object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

Action isArray

`isArray – {boolean=} – If true then the returned object for this action is an array, see returns section.`

According to your code isArray = true.  Set it to false and you can use an object instead of an array.

```
app.factory('itemService', function ($resource) {
return {
        getCategoryAndBrand   :  $resource("/user/categories_brands" ,{},{ TypeGetCategoryAndBrand:{method: 'get', isArray:true}})
    };
});
```

It's expecting you to pass in the parameters as an array not an object

from your code

`$resource("/user/categories_brands" ,{},{ TypeGetCategoryAndBrand:{method: 'get', isArray:true}})`

If the documentation is to be believed than with the error your getting I'd try to pass this in the form of an array and not an object to see if you get the same response.

Comment: the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) explicitly says, that both optional parameters (what the square brackets stand for) are of type Object/ Hash.

Comment: How is this the best answer? As @erndenson notes, square brackets stand for optional and not array. :/

Comment: I changed this for accuracy.  My original response was wrong, though it fixed the issue because it was expecting an array, but only because the isArray action was set to true.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the API server was returning an HTML page (an error page) that is treated as a string, instead of the correct JSON response which would be a javascript object.

As a sidenote, javascript errors and stacktraces are really something.

Comment: I had a similar situation, using Rails backend, my example app was serving both html and json by default so  
`$resource('/posts/:id', {id: '@id'})`  
gave the same error as initially mentioned above.  
Adding json to the /posts reference was a quick fix  
`$resource('/posts.json/:id', {id: '@id'})`  
although of course it would be better to serve json only from the backend

Answer (score 4):

Hope this answer is not too late.

You should not fix this problem by putting a isArray:true statement to override "get" method's nature in your resource declaration.

There are two ways to fix this problem.

1.Use "query" method instead. It works like "get" method totally, but its isArray is set to true naturally.

```
TypeGetCategoryAndBrand:{method: 'query'}
```

2.On the server side, responding an object is a much easier and much smarter way. You can continue using "get" method on your client side and change your server side code from this:

```
res.jsonp(articles);
```

where articles is the result array, to this:

```
res.jsonp(articles[0]);
```

Comment: "Use "query" method instead. It works like "get" method totally, but its isArray is set to true naturally." ... spot on for me :-)

Comment: JSON encoding was my issue. Thanks

Comment: Saved my life. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an object that contain two arrays.

My guess is that in your code before you started with the `console.log` outputs, you were setting `categories = response;`.

You need to set it to:
`categories = response.categories;`

Here:

```
app.controller('itemsFormController', function ($rootScope, $scope, itemService, $location, $cookies, $routeParams) {
        itemService.getCategoryAndBrand.TypeGetCategoryAndBrand({}, function(response){

                categories = response.categories;
                console.log(response);

            },function(errorResponse){
                console.log(errorResponse);
            }
        );  
});
```

This might help to understand the problem, also:

[AngularJS $resource query returns array with a function in it, which is not does not fit well when iterating through data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968274/angularjs-resource-query-returns-array-with-a-function-in-it-which-is-not-does)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solve for me from [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

```
app.factory('Article', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/v1/a/:id', null,
        {
            'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:false},
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
}]);
```