# AngularJS $resource query returns array with a function in it, which is not does not fit well when iterating through data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have added a custom Array.prototype.functionName to my js file. I am using AngularJS 1.2.3
and when I call $resource to return a query, it appends that custom function in the response array. when i iterate over the response array, it return exceptions when parsing the custom function, that is what i believe. Can anyone suggest me how to work around this problem

```
Array.prototype.functionName = function(){
    //sorting
}
```

I call my $resource like this in my service

```
return $resource('/url',{},{
    'List':{
         method: 'GET',
         isArray: true
    }
});
```

and call it in my controller

```
returnResource.List().$promise.then(function(Data){
    console.log(Data); //Data has my custom function append at the end
    for(var i in Data){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure if you fully understand how resource works.. can you update the post to show the url you want to call ?

Comment: You need to give us the code that is crashing, because I just successfully tested your example.   http://plnkr.co/edit/HwSBYEo8xfPiH2WC8QWP

Comment: in my $promise.then function, I iterate over the response Data, which i get from Django rest framework, looks like [b,b,b,b,...,$promise,$resolved,functionName]. it renders all the b objects but throws exception at the end and terminates my iteration. if I comment out functionName definition, it doesn't show up in Data but still shows the same exception

Comment: Can you update the above and show how you are iterating?  Both angular.forEach and array.forEach work...

Comment: @Nix i have edited, how I am iterating over Data, I think i try should use angular.forEach

Comment: Yes, or use the native array forEach (assuming u have browser support (ie9+)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looping over the `properties([0],[1], length, $promise, etc)` of the array versus the items.

For `in` is not correct in this case that says hey I want to loop over every property of this array which includes the array items, but it also includes some other ng-resource`y things.

You should be using `angular.forEach`, `Data.forEach`, or go old school and use a `for(i;i<Data.length;i++)`

I can see you don't fully understand what `ng-resource` is returning;  The response from the query/array looks like this:

```
sort me![Resource, Resource, $promise: Object, $resolved: true, ...]
0: Resource
  id: "nix"
  __proto__: Resource
1: Resource
  id: "nix2"
  __proto__: Resource
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
    .. array funcs
    forEach: function forEach() {
        [native code]
    }
    functionName: function () {
    }
     ...
```

[Plunkr for your example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HwSBYEo8xfPiH2WC8QWP?p=preview)

```
Array.prototype.functionName = function(){
    //sorting
    console.log("what is this...?", this, this.length);
    this.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item);
    });
}

app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.resource = $resource('url.json',{},{
                    'List':{
                         method: 'GET',
                         isArray: true
                    }
                });

    $scope.resource.List().$promise.then(
        function(data){
            console.log("List", this);
            data.functionName();
    });
   $scope.resource.query().$promise.then(
        function(data){

            console.log("query", this);
            data.functionName();

    });    

});
```

---

I included the out of the box way to do REST `List` using the query.  Your `List` call and my `Query` call are doing the exact same thing they are hitting the url `/Api` and are expecting an array to be returned.