# Angular $resource - Expected response to contain an array but got an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm using a $resource in Angular, and have set up the resource like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('Appointment', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/admin/:id', { id: "@_id" }, {
         query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
    });
})
```

Now, when I use this resource in one controller (adminController) it works ok:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('adminController', ['$scope', 'Appointment', '$state', '$rootScope' , '$stateParams', '$log', '$modal','uiGmapGoogleMapApi',  function($scope, Appointment, $state, $rootScope, $stateParams, $log, $modal, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
$scope.apps  = Appointment.query();
```

}])

but when I try to use it in another one (DetailCtrl) i get the above error:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', 'Appointment', '$state', '$rootScope' , '$stateParams', '$log', '$modal', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', function($scope, Appointment, $state, $rootScope, $stateParams, $log, $modal, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

$scope.detail = Appointment.query({id: $stateParams.id})

}])
```

can anyone explain what it going on? I'm getting this error:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration for action `query`. Expected response to contain an array but got an object
```

Comment: In what form you transfer data to a request from the server?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020087/how-to-fix-expected-response-to-contain-an-array-but-got-an-object-angular-js

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling it the first time, you are not passing in an `id` parameter, so you end up actually calling the URL `/api/admin/`, which apparently returns an array.

The second call in `DetailCtrl` is passing an id, so it is calling a different URL, say `/api/admin/12`, and this service is returning a single object, so you get the error you describe.

You need different $resources for the different expected return values - the same call will not be able to return both an array and a single object.

In my own code, I would split it up something like:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('Appointment', function ($resource) {

    return {

        list: $resource('/api/admin', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true }
        })

        single: $resource('/api/admin/:id', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false }
        })

    };

});
```

And you could fetch a list with

$scope.apps  = Appointment.list.query();

and a single appointment with

$scope.detail = Appointment.single.query({id: $stateParams.id});

Comment: thanks for this - i'm basically an idiot - i should be calling Appointment.get - not Appointment.query for a single object